# MPMoviePlayerController endPlaybackTime not working in iOS 9

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, ios9, mpmovieplayer

I am playing a video using MPMovieController and i am setting the start and end playback times. It worked before, but since updating to ios 9 the code does not work anymore. I use the following code:

```
self.player.initialPlaybackTime = self.startPlaybackTime;

self.player.endPlaybackTime = self.endPlaybackTime;
self.player.currentPlaybackTime = self.startPlaybackTime;
```

I tried using this code before calling `[self.player prepareToPlay]`and when playbackState is changed to MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying using the following code:

```
-(void)MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    if (self.player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying)
    {
        if (!self.playbackDurationSet)
        {
            self.player.initialPlaybackTime = self.startPlaybackTime;
            self.player.endPlaybackTime = self.endPlaybackTime;
            self.player.currentPlaybackTime = self.startPlaybackTime;

            self.playbackDurationSet = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

In the first option the initialPlabackTime/currentPlaybackTime also don't work. In the second option the movie does not end when it should. How can i fix this?